# Entity Framework 7 Application Role

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EF6 it was possible to use System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception to implement Application Roles for MS SQL Server. I cannot find any reference to Interception in the EF7 libraries. In the Roadmap for EF7 it lists "Simple interception mechanisms for query and updates" as a high priority. Will this provide the functionality to implement app roles? If it does that's great BUT is there some reason app roles have to be hidden behind such obscurity? Why can't we simply have DbContext properties for app role username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Rowan Miller, Microsoft Program Manager, provided some guidance which led to this solution to the problem. In summary, add a constructor to the generated DbContext which opens the connection and executes sp_setapprole. If you don't open the connection first the connection will be closed after sp_setapprole and you will lose the app role before executing your subsequent query. At some point this capability may appear in an EF7 Interception library but this strategy works with EF7 RC1.

```
public partial class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Database.OpenConnection();
            this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC sp_setapprole appRole, appPsw");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```